# Unity 2D - Camera isn't where it's supposed to be

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, 2d

In Unity 2D, I am working on a game that uses a square shaped camera that hovers over a tilemap (Zelda NES style). In the camera preview in the game view, it shows what it's supposed to:

[image]

But when I switch to the game view, this is what it shows:

[image]

Here are my camera settings in case it helps.

[image]

Does anybody know why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out how to fix it. All I needed to do was set "Depth" on the camera settings to 0 (it was at -1 before).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You scene must have multiple cameras and one of those camera's depth would be > -1 hence its showing that camera and not your maincamera, if you just have one camera the depth does not matter